# Use Jackson Objectmapper configured by Spring boot in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-types

I want to configure Hibernate to use Jackson's `Objectmapper` created by Spring to map between json and entities. In the project I'm working on I already configured Jooq to use the Spring's `ObjectMapper` but I'm having trouble how to configure Hibernate to use it. **The goal** in the end is that both Jooq and Hibernate would use the same `ObjectMapper`.

I checked this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-types-customize-jackson-objectmapper/) by Vlad. Unfortunately all the tips given in the article don't work for the project I'm working on.

Here's an example configuration I tried

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfiguration implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {
    //Autowire Objectmapper created by Spring
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        ObjectMapperSupplier objectMapperSupplier = () -> objectMapper;
        // Below config doesn't work since Hibernate types creates it's own mapper
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.types.jackson.object.mapper", objectMapperSupplier);
}
```

Also tried the same approach by adding the Objectmapper to hibernate-types.properties.

```
#Used by Hibernate but cannot get reference of Spring managed ObjectMapper since this is class is called outside of Spring's context.
hibernate.types.jackson.object.mapper=path.to.ObjectMapperSupplier
```

Another approach I used but it fails with a `NullpointerException` when converting from JSON to an entity in `JsonTypeDescriptor` class.

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfiguration implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer{

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        // Underlying implementation needs some JavaType or propertyClass, otherwise when converting 
        // from JSON we get a nullpointer.
        var jsonBinaryType = new JsonBinaryType(objectMapper);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.type_contributors", (TypeContributorList) () -> 
        Collections.singletonList((typeContributions, serviceRegistry) -> 
                      typeContributions.contributeType(jsonBinaryType)));
}
```

Below is the type declaration for entity super class.

```
// This makes Hibernate types create it's own mapper.
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity{

}
```

So, are there any possible solutions how I can hook up Spring managed ObjectMapper to Hibernate?

Answer (score 12):

For those working on Spring Boot 3 and Hibernate 6, check [this solution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33870#issuecomment-1386822021) from Andy Wilkinson:

```
    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer jsonFormatMapperCustomizer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return properties -> properties
                .put(AvailableSettings.JSON_FORMAT_MAPPER, new JacksonJsonFormatMapper(objectMapper));
    }
```

Comment: Works for me as well.
Finally a pretty solution.
Thx :-)

Comment: THANKS!! I was searching of how to register JavaTimeModule (to parse correctly dates from jsonb fields) in my Java17+Hibernate6+SpringBoot3 app for several days. And your answer saved me! :)

Answer (score 6):

I finally figured this out, but it is kind of an creative solution...

TLDR: I have a bean that stores the Spring-configured `objectMapper` in a static field. A BeanFactoryPostProcessor ensures that this bean is initialized before Hibernate (types) tries to load / get the ObjectMapper.

**hibernate.properties**

```
hibernate.types.jackson.object.mapper=com.github.lion7.example.HibernateObjectMapperSupplier
```

**HibernateObjectMapperSupplier.kt**

```kotlin
package com.github.lion7.example

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.ObjectMapperSupplier
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

class HibernateObjectMapperSupplier : ObjectMapperSupplier {
    override fun get(): ObjectMapper =
        ObjectMapperHolder.objectMapper
}

@Component
class ObjectMapperHolder(objectMapper: ObjectMapper) {

    companion object {
        lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper
    }

    init {
        Companion.objectMapper = objectMapper
    }

}

@Component
class ObjectMapperDependencyFixer : BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    override fun postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory: ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) {
        val beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("entityManagerFactory")
        val oldDependsOn = beanDefinition.dependsOn ?: emptyArray()
        val newDependsOn = oldDependsOn + "objectMapperHolder"
        beanDefinition.setDependsOn(*newDependsOn)
    }
}
```

Same code as gist: https://gist.github.com/lion7/c8006b69a309e38183deb69124b888b5

Comment: thanks for the answer, works like charm 

Comment: We can also use this configuration key in `application.yml`(instead of hibernate specific configs): `jpa.properties.hibernate.types.jackson.object.mapper: your_path`

Answer (score 2):

I think that I've found solution to do it programmatically (without magic with fixing dependency graph).
**HibernateConfiguration.kt**

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(
        objectMapper: ObjectMapper // Thanks to that Spring can create correct dependency graph
    ): HibernatePropertiesCustomizer =
        HibernatePropertiesCustomizer { hibernateProperties ->
            HibernateObjectMapperSupplier.objectMapper = objectMapper
            hibernateProperties["hibernate.types.jackson.object.mapper"] = HibernateObjectMapperSupplier::class.qualifiedName
        }
}
```

**HibernateObjectMapperSupplier.kt**

```
class HibernateObjectMapperSupplier : Supplier<ObjectMapper> {

    override fun get(): ObjectMapper {
        return objectMapper
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Java implementation.

```java
@Component
public class HibernateObjectMapper implements Supplier<ObjectMapper> {

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public void setObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        HibernateObjectMapper.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper get() {
        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

If you define your own JPA beans, simply add `@DependsOn("hibernateObjectMapper")` to their config. Otherwise you need a `BeanPostProcessor` to add the dependency to the autoconfigured bean:

```java
@Component
class HibernateBeanDependencyProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory) {
        BeanDefinition beanDefinition = factory.getBeanDefinition("entityManagerFactory");
        String[] dependsOn = beanDefinition.getDependsOn();
        dependsOn = dependsOn == null ? new String[]{} : dependsOn;
        String[] newDependsOn = new String[dependsOn.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(dependsOn, 0, newDependsOn, 1, dependsOn.length);
        newDependsOn[0] = "hibernateObjectMapper";
        beanDefinition.setDependsOn(newDependsOn);
    }
}
```

As for the property, `hibernate.types.*` don't work when set programmatically. The library looks directly in the `hibernate.properties`, `hibernate-types.properties`, and `application.properties` files.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.getProperties().put(
    Configuration.PropertyKey.JACKSON_OBJECT_MAPPER.getKey(),
    MyObjectMapperSupplier.class.getName()
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @EslamSamehAhmed: Which link?

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked best for me is to configure the already existing `ObjectMapper` used by Hypersistence:

```
   import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.util.ObjectMapperWrapper;
   
   ObjectMapperWrapper.INSTANCE.getObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```